# The XML content that is supplied for the sparse column set 'tp_ColumnSet' contains duplicate references to the column 'int1'

Tags: updatelistitems

I am getting below error while updating list item

> *SqlError: 'The XML content that is supplied for the sparse column set 'tp_ColumnSet' contains duplicate references to the column 'int1'. A
>   column can only be referenced once in XML content supplied to a sparse
>   column set.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 9525
>   State: 1 Class: 16 Procedure: 'proc_UpdateListItem' LineNumber: 288
>   Server: 'server'*

Strange part of the error is this is only if i update an item from powershell and if i update an item from UI its works without any issue.

Also i found that two of my fields' **ColName property** is '**int1**'. If this is the root cause of the issue how it is working from UI and not from PowerShell. Is there a way to fix this duplication issue?

Below is the powershell scrip i am using

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity "url"
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["listname"]
$spListItem = $spList.Items.GetItemById(1)
$spListItem["fieldname"] = "fieldValue"
$spListItem.Update()
```

Comment: Can you update question with PowerShell script.

Comment: @AmalHashim updated

Comment: You said field is of type number. Can you try `$spListItem["fieldname"] = 123` instead?

Comment: @AmalHashim its a lookup field

Answer (score 0):

Lookup fields should be updated in a different way as below

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity "url"
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["listname"]
$lookuplist = $spWeb.Lists["lookuplistname"]

$spListItem = $spList.Items.GetItemById(1)

$lookupitem = $lookuplist.GetItemById(1)  #lookup item id          
$lookupvalue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($lookupitem.ID,$lookupitem.ID.ToString());            
$spListItem["lookupfield"] = $lookupvalue;            
$spListItem.Update();
```

Comment: This is not the solution. The problem is with the internal column name. Two field is pointing to same internal column which is ColName property of field.

Comment: Internal name should be unique. Can you review using SharePoint Manager or PowerShell?

Comment: Its uniquer. There is no duplication in internal name but the duplication is in the metadata property which is ColName.